# Postgres: insert value from another table as part of multi-row insert?

Tags: postgresql

I am working in Postgres 9.6 and would like to insert multiple rows in a single query, using an `INSERT INTO` query.

I would also like, as one of the values inserted, to select a value from another table.

This is what I've tried:

```
insert into store_properties (property, store_id) 
values 
  ('ice cream', select id from store where postcode='SW1A 1AA'),
  ('petrol', select id from store where postcode='EC1N 2RN')
;
```

But I get a syntax error at the first `select`. What am I doing wrong?

Note that the value is determined per row, i.e. I'm not straightforwardly copying over values from another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=39cb8d743fde277c6131bfbea36b300d)

```
insert into store_properties (property, store_id) 
values 
('ice cream', (select id from store where postcode='SW1A 1AA')),
('petrol', (select id from store where property='EC1N 2RN'))
```

There were some missing braces. Each data set has to be surrounded by braces and the `SELECT` statements as well.

I don't know your table structure but maybe there is another error: The first data set is filtered by a `postcode` column, the second one by a `property` column...

Comment: @Richard You're welcome: I would appreciate if you could upvote as well